# CSS styling differences between http and https

Tags: html, css

I have the problem, that my website acts different if I call it via the `https` protocol. To be more precise it looks like it handles the CSS in a different way.

What I want (and how it actually works via `http`) is kind of a navigation with different tabs. Here is an image of the navigation part:
[http navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2GT6.jpg)

And here is an image of how it looks like when it's called via `https`:
[https navigation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysHmp.jpg)

I have also created a fiddle with this part of my website although it does not proper work inside the fiddle. (maybe because the jsfiddle site is also via https protocol?)
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/muLu8k2a/9/)

However, please have a look at the current website to see the difference:
This is the website via http:
[http website](http://www.turnverein-kraig.net/#angebot)

and here how it looks like when it's called via https:
[https website](https://www.turnverein-kraig.net/#angebot)

You guys ever had a similar problem or any idea how to solve it?
I was the opinion that the protocol should not make a difference.

Comment: What browser are you using to view this in?

Comment: take a look at the console and you will have the idea -- a hint : mixed content

Comment: The issue is with the width being wrongly used. Make sure `padding`s and `margin`s are working fine with `box-sizing` styles.

Comment: sorry, i tried it with chrome, firefox and internet explorer.

Comment: Disabling all the `width` styles on menu `li` makes it work just fine.

Comment: @lolbas

yes, i've tried to disable the widh styles - but i actually want each tab to be exactely 25% widh - so it fills the entire box.

i  want to avoid disabling the widths it it's somehow possible

Comment: 1 more question. What can i do to improve the score of this question?
I don't know what i did wrong that it has a negative score?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be deleted instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Comment: @Glorfindel The fact that the answer is upvoted and accepted seems to suggest that at least some people find the Q&A useful. But the fact that the OP appears to have gotten the answer to their question just makes the vandalism even worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at your console.

You should see a lot of `Mixed Content` errors or warnings if you are using Chrome.

When a website is served over HTTPS, all its resources must be served over HTTPS too. When a resource is not loaded over HTTPS, the browser will block it because otherwise it defeats the whole purpose of using a HTTPS.

When one resource is blocked, the content from these resources won't get executed. Maybe that is the reason why your layout breaks because something is not being executed properly.

So try to change your resources into HTTPS protocol. If you are using APIs and those API does not provide HTTPS link, then you should look for another API.

**In your case**

This is the culprit.

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic
```

You can find it in `head` section.

Your font should be in `Source Sans Pro` but because it was blocked, `Helvetica` or `Arial` was used instead. Thus breaking the layout.

Change it to HTTPS and it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, awesome.
Now i look stupid. :D
Looking at the console should be the first thing to do.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know much about HTTP requests, but I can tell you two things:
- The browser cascades and parses CSS in different ways. HTTPS requests are processed in different ways. Maybe check you cascade.
- That website looks nice

Comment: `The browser cascades and parses CSS in different ways.` --> what ??

Comment: HTTP/2 an evolution of SPDY maybe? Requests are handled differently but that doesn't change anything to the result, once a page and its resources are loaded.

Comment: @TemaniAfif When CSS Code is written, the cascade is the hierarchy in which elements appear. Some browsers, do things differrently. Maybe he did not add a universal reset. Which is: * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}